# Issue when a Standard view page is redirected to the Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

**Problem Statement:**

I have a `Visualforce Page` written in my org which is used to override the **'NEW'** button of the **'SAMPLE'** object. This `Visualforce Page` also opens up when the **'Sample Record is Edited'**. We need to show this `Visualforce Page` even when the **'Sample Record is viewed'**. For this as of now there is one more `Visualforce Page` which has been added to the **'Standard Layout'** of the Sample and this `Visualforce Page` is again redirecting it to the first `Visualforce Page`.

Since when the Sample Record is opened then the 2 `Visualforce Page` are loaded, so the redirection time is becoming more thus displaying the 'Standard Sample Page' for some seconds before finally opening the `Visualforce Page` layout.

There are some mandatory fields on the 'Standard Layout' which cannot be removed and shows up initially thus not looking good and creating some confusion.

Below is the snapshot how it shows up for some seconds.

[image: Standard View With Inline Visualforce Page]

Below is the `Visualforce Page` how it should show up.

[image: Visualforce Page Only]

Below is the code in the `Visualforce Page` which is kept of the 'Standard Layout' and then is redirected to the 1st `Visualforce Page`.

[image: Visualforce Markup]

[image: Apex Code]

Is there any way to directly put the `Visualforce Page` which has to show up instead of redirecting it with another page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a Javascript redirect, you should directly set an override on the objects page.

I don't want to copy and paste the official docs, or appear mean buy saying 'RTFM!' but a full guide that will help you achieve what you are doing is decribed in a really nice way on this offical SalesForce guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm

Once you have created your new visualforce page, you need to setup the override on the object, you can do this by:

> 1. From the object management settings for your object, go to Buttons,
>      Links, and Actions.
> 2. Click Edit next to View.
> 3. For Override With
>
>    - select Visualforce Page. From the Visualforce Page drop-down list,
>    - select your new custom page. Click Save.

Comment: Actually, pasting in a quote from the docs is highly encouraged. Link-only answers can break over time and are discouraged without including the relevant content.